# HttpUtility.ParseQueryString without decoding special characters

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, urlencode

```
Uri uri = new Uri(redirectionUrl);
NameValueCollection col = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query)
```

`uri.Query` is already decoded - so is there any way I can prevent `ParseQueryString` decoding it again?

Apart from that - is there another method to retrieve a name value collection from a Uri **without** modifying any components?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Encoding the `uri.Query` before passing it to `ParseQueryString` is the first thing that comes to my head.

**UPDATE**

Just checked the `ParseQueryString` method with Reflector: it assumes that the query string is encoded and you can't do anything with it... Bummer. So I think you need to parse it manually (there are plenty of ready-to-use algorithms on the Web).

Alternatively you could encode your query string properly (taking into account variable names and all special characters) before passing it to `ParseQueryString` method.

-- Pavel

Comment: I can't as uri.Query includes the variable name and ? =

Comment: I've updated my answer. Hope this will help you to do a right decision.

Answer (score -4):

I have faced the same problem. The solution is adding the second parameter - the encoding. It seams that everything works if you set UTF8 encoding.

```
NameValueCollection col = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query, Encoding.UTF8)
```

Comment: UTF8 encoding is used by default, so adding it explicitly does not have any effect: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This option does not have any effect

Comment: This unfortunately does not have any effect. You should encode your query string properly prior to passing it to ParseQueryString.