# ASP.NET MVC 5 TryUpdateModel not allowing & in string

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Starting with an original string of: "Text=AB&C", this value is passed through the HttpUtility.ParseQueryString to create a NameValueCollection.

Then to create the IValueProvider for the TryUpdateModel, the NameValueCollection creates a new NameValueCollectionProdvier.

At this point in the NameValueCollectionValueProvider, the Key becomes Text and the Value still remains AB&C.

When the TryUpdateModel is called passing in the values, the Text changes from AB&C to AB.

Any thoughts on why this might be?

Here is the code:

e is from a foreach that was passed in to the Controller ActionResult model value

```
foreach (string e in model.Elements)
{
    string queryString = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(e);
    var model = new Model();
    NameValueCollection nameValues = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString);
        // nameValues = {Text=AB&C} at this point
    var provider = new NameValueCollectionValueProvider(nameValues, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture);
        // provider = NameValueCollectionValueProvider at this point
        // It's _values has a Count=1
        // which at index [0] has this value {[Text, System.Web.Mvc.NameValueCollectionProvider+ValueProviderResultPlaceholder]}
        // which has a Key of "Text"
        // and a Value of System.Web.Mvc.NameValueCollectionProvider
        // within that Value, it's broken down with some properties
        // System.Web.Mvc.NameValueCollectionProvider
        // _validatedCollection and _unvalidatedCollection both have a value of Text=AB&C
        // but I see now that the ValidatedResult and the UnvalidatedResult both have a value of AB
    TryUpdateModel(model, provider);
```

The model's Text value is declared as `public string Text { get; set; }` so the TryUpdateModel does find the matching Text declaration.

Updated:

I found that within the NameValueCollectionValueProvider, the provider's Value has an _unvalidatedCollection and a _validatedCollection with my expected result of Text=AB&C but the UnvalidatedResult and the ValidatedResult within the provider both have a value of AB.

It seems that the provider is removing values after the &.

Can the provider itself be further encoded to maintain the & in the string?

Comment: I think `AB&C` sould be UrlEncoded ...

Comment: I did just come across this answer which sounds like there is nothing I can do about this and have to parse is manually to maintain the "special" characters I want

http://stackoverflow.com/a/4604759/1040188

Unless there is another solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to encode when you are building the url and decode when you are trying to read url params
`string queryString = "Text=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("AB&C")`;

Comment: This is already after encoding. The original string was passed in as AB%26C. After encoding the value becomes AB&C. It's only during the TryUpdateModel that the characters after & get removed. I want to maintain the & in the Text.

Comment: I think you meant after decoding, I don't think your problem is at TryUpdateModel, It should be at NameValueCollection nameValues = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString); It should be parsing Text,AB. Try with "Text=AB&C=y", It will give you Text,AB and C,y. Your code is getting C as a second variable on the query string.

Comment: I understand what you mean where the NameValueCollection sees the & as a second variable on the query string. Thanks